# How to detect customization in a Salesforce organization

Tags: customization, org

my organization has a very complex Salesforce instance. We have over 900 organizations defined and are striving to simplify.

I need some help understand the effort required to understand the amount of customization in each of the organizations.

We are striving to consolidate the organizations which have no customization or minimal customization into 1 organizations.

I know next 2 nothing about Salesforce technology but I need to know if this is a multi-week effort or just a couple of days.

Comment: When you say 900 organizations are you talking separate salesforce orgs for each organization? If so then you are talking a lot of time to analyze business requirements or each organization and then a lot of time to develop a consolidation plan. This is not a weeks thing, it is months or more

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways to figure that out (especially since you are new to Salesforce) is to use an available tool which can compare orgs and quickly point out any differences/ customisations between the large number of orgs that you have.

I use [copado deployer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3dgGEAR) (not endorsing in any manner though) which helps quickly scan through multiple orgs to spot customisations and metadata differences.